# jqgrid reload grid on cell edit only for a specific cell

Tags: jqgrid

```
afterSaveCell: function () { $(this).trigger('reloadGrid');},
```

If I put this in my grid it works well, reloads the grid after a cell edit.  Is there an easy or known way to reload only on a specific cell ? something like

```
//afterSaveCell: function () {
If(the field is budgetyear1){
  $(this).trigger('reloadGrid');}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should always place the call of `trigger('reloadGrid')` inside of `setTimeout`. It's important because `trigger('reloadGrid')` works *synchronously* and the next line after `trigger('reloadGrid')` will be executed only after reload is finished. If you reload the data from the server, then it's not so critical, but some internal parameters of jqGrid can be already reset (the `page` number for example).

About you main question: `afterSaveCell` will be called with 5 parameters: `rowid`, `columnName`, `cellValue`, `iRow`, `iCol`. It gives you enough information about the clicked cell and you can use `getCell` method to get information about any other columns of the row. Thus your could be about the following:

```js
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, columnName, cellValue, iRow, iCol) {
    var $self = $(this); // cache this to be used later in `setTimeout`

    if (/*test some conditions*/) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
        }, 50);
    }
}
```